# Doing two string manipulations in puppet

Tags: puppet

I am running puppet 3.8.6

In a template, I need to truncate the last four characters then remove hyphens from a string parameter.  For example "foo-bar.txt" should become "foobar".

val[0..-5] works for truncating the last four characters.

val.gsub('-','') works for removing the hyphen.

But this is a syntax error.

val[0..-5].gsub('-','')

How can I do both?

Comment: I can't reproduce a syntax error here using Puppet 3.8.6. Are you sure?

Comment: Could you supply your code?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment on your post... I don't think your example would produce a syntax error. However, though this is a little more verbose, I find splitting to be easier to reason about than removing slices of the string. This ought to work, too:

```
val.split('.')[0].gsub('-','')
```

Edit: I somehow missed that this was inside a template. Oops! I've updated as Alex Harvey suggested in the comments.

Comment: Remember, this is embedded Ruby in an ERB template, so $ denotes global variable. Probably this would be more correct and idiomatic: `val.split('.')[0].gsub('-','')`.